# Problem with checking all checkboxes

Tags: android, checkedtextview

I have 2 problems.

The 1st problem.
I have a CheckedTextView "Select All" item and a list of array items set in a adapter of MutipleChoice. I am current trying to set the state of all the checkboxes of the array items to true/false by selecting the CheckedTextView. It works but there's a bug. Such that when the last item of the array is true, the "SelectAll" to true will work, but if the last item of the array is false, it will uncheck all the items. What I want is even if any of the item's state is false, it will be set to true when the checkedtextview is selected to true.

The 2nd problem.
I can't seem to set the checkedtextview to true when all of the array item's state is true.

Could it be that I'm doing it the wrong way? Help given would be appreciated..

This is my method for the CheckedTextView "Select All"

```
private void markAll (Boolean state) {

    for (int i = 0; i < lv.getCount(); i++) {
        lv.setItemChecked(i, state);
    }           
}
```

This is the coding for checking of the states of the array items

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    for(int i = 0; i < lv.getCount(); i++) {
        //if even 1 of the item is false, the checkedtextview will be set to false
        if(lv.isItemChecked(i) == false) {
            ctv.setChecked(false);
        }
        //if all of the item is true, the checkedtextview will be set to true as well
        //the coding should be done in the if-else below, if i'm not wrong
        if(...) {

        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
This is the new code for calling my method
        ctv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ctv.setClickable(true);
            if(ctv.isPressed() && ctv.isChecked() == false) {
                ctv.setChecked(true);
                markAll(true);
            }
            else {
                ctv.setChecked(false);
                markAll(false);
            }
        }
    });
```

This is my xml code for the checkedtextview

```
    <CheckedTextView
        android:id="@+id/checkedtext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:text="Select all"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:paddingRight="6dip"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this reworked logic:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    ctv.setChecked(true); // assume true at first

    // if even 1 of the item is false, the checkedtextview will be set to false
    for(int i = 0; i < lv.getCount(); i++) {
        if(lv.isItemChecked(i) == false) {
            ctv.setChecked(false);
            break; // exit loop if you have found one false
        }
    }
}
```

This will make your `ctv` have the checked state if all of the items in the list are checked, otherwise if any are false then `ctv` will have the unchecked state.

To control what happens when you click `ctv` itself:

```
ctv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(ctv.isChecked()) {
                markAll(true); // ctv is checked, so make all others checked
        }
        else {
              markAll(false); // ctv is unchecked, so make all others unchecked
        }
    }
});
```

You don't need to check state of other items here - if it is just a '(de)select all' button then it should just propagate its own state to the other items.

Comment: Wow! Fast reply. And.... THANKS IT WORKS!!! I didn't think of adding ing a break and assuming the ctv is true 1st. Thanks alot man ^^. And is it possible if i ask u another question? About CheckedTextView as well..

Comment: Of course you can :) But you maybe you should create another question instead of adding to this one if the problem can standalone by itself. Then others could see it more clearly too.

Comment: Oh, there seems to be a problem with the code you gave me. It seems that after applying your code, the situation has reversed such that if the last item of the array is not true, the ctv will uncheck the rest of the array items.

Comment: The code I gave you does not uncheck anything other than ctv itself. Can you show how you are calling your 'markAll()' function?

Comment: I have edited my original post for your new problem. I think it should now behave how you want...

Comment: Hmm.. It doesn't work. My ctv is unable to be checked so your method would not work. Maybe its something to do with my xml code. I have posted my CheckedTextView xml code above.

Comment: Okay problem solved. I have edited my post above for the Select All